# Como puedo realizar una conversión de un numero a un array

Tags: array, c, números-enteros

intento realizar la conversión de un numero a un arreglo, de manera que:

Ej: numero 20342; a[0] = 2, a[1] = 0, a[2] = 3, a[3] = 4, a[4] = 2

A continuación mi código, la funcion conversion es lo que intenté concretamente para cumplir el objetivo, pero no resulta:

```
int *conversion(int numero){
     return numero + "0";
}

int main(){
    int n, cantidad = 10;
    char valor, check;
    printf("Ingrese n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *numero = conversion(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo, nunca usas la función (`conversion`) que declaraste al inicio  y luego de pedir los datos del usuario nunca haces algo con ellos. Dices que quieres convertir todo a un arreglo, pero nunca defines un arreglo en ningún lado de tu código.

Comment: Tiene razón, ya edité el código

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil obtener los datos del usuario como si fuesen una string? Pregunto esto ya que una string es en sí un array de caracteres, que parece ser lo que buscas. No sé si necesitas hacerlo de la manera en la que lo estás haciendo, pero de igual manera existen maneras para convertir un número a una string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer la conversión leyendo el número como una secuencia de caracteres:

```
char numero[10];
scanf("%s", numero);
for( int i=0; i<strlen(numero); i++ )
    printf("%c ", numero[i]);
```

O puedes leer el dato como un entero y separar sus dígitos matemáticamente. Nota que en este ocasión en la posición 0 obtienes el dígito de menor peso:

```
int numero;
scanf("%d", &numero);
int secuencia[10];
for( int i=0; numero!=0; i++ )
{
    secuencia[i] = numero % 10;
    numero /= 10;

    printf("%d ", secuencia[i]);
}
```